# How to pass a formData object and another object inside array with Axios JS

Tags: javascript, forms, object, axios, form-data

Hello I have a simple problem. I have two objects in Javascript I am trying to pass together to my server using Axios.

First, a simple object with simple properties and values:

```
        var object1 = {
            type: {color: "red", variants: [1,2,4,5]},
            content: "xxx"
        }
```

Also a second object which contains File images

```
        let imagesLocalForm = new FormData(); 
        this.imagesLocal.forEach(img => {
            imagesLocalForm.append("productPhotos[]", img[0]);
        });
```

Sending either object by themselves will successfully transfer the data to the server. HOWEVER, once I combine the data into an array or another object then all the images from the form object will disappear. ex:

```
var data = [object1, imagesLocalForm];
```

or

```
var data = {info: object1, images: imagesLocalForm};
```

I use this Axios code to post the data:

```
        Axios.post(this.ADD_MULTI_PRODUCT_API_ENDPOINT, data)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

When i `dd()` the data array, the response I receive is:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "type" => array:2 [
      "color" => "red"
      "variants" => array:4 [
        0 => 1
        1 => 2
        2 => 4
        3 => 5
      ]
    ]
    "content" => "xxx"
  ]
  1 => []
]
```

When i `dd()` from my php server i receive all of my `object1` data but none of the `imagesLocalForm` data. Could someone explain this behavior to me?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot post JSON data *and* form data to the same endpoint, it'd simply be impossible because the request body can only have one content type. But you can add you additional data to your existing `FormData` object.

To do that:

```js
let imagesLocalForm = new FormData(); 

this.imagesLocal.forEach(img => {
  imagesLocalForm.append("productPhotos[]", img[0]);
});

const object1 = {
  type: "big",
  content: "xxx"
}

for (const key of Object.keys(object1)) {
  imagesLocalForm.append(key, object1[key]);
}
```

Then you can just pass `imagesLocalForm` to your backend endpoint

Comment: ahh i should have mentioned a better example as the `object1` has another simple object inside. I will revise the question. i have already tried that method and received [object Object] string as the data. the only current method that seems to work is to stringify the object with JSON